# Netlogo is working but behaviorspace is showing garbage

Tags: netlogo, behaviorspace

I am running the following code:

```
breed [houses house]
breed [buyers buyer]
houses-own [value visitors bought]  
buyers-own [visited wealth bought]

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks

  create-houses 100 [
   move-to one-of patches with [not any? houses-here]
   set shape "house"
   set color 125
   set value (who + 100)                         
   set visitors []
  ]

  create-buyers 100 [
   move-to one-of patches with [not any? turtles-here]
   set shape "person"
   set color yellow
   set wealth who   
   set visited []
  ]
end


to go
  repeat 5 [
    ask buyers [
      move-to one-of houses with [bought = 0]
      set visited fput ([value] of houses-here) visited        
      
      ask houses-here [
        set visitors fput ([wealth] of buyers-here) visitors
      ]
      
      move-to one-of patches with [not any? turtles-here ]
    ]
  ]
  
  ask buyers [
    if length visited > 0 [
      set visited reduce sentence visited
    ]
  ]
  
  ask houses [
    if length visitors > 0 [
      set visitors reduce sentence visitors
    ]
  ]
  
  tick
end
```

Which compiles a list of houses that each buyer has visited (see `visited`) and a list for each house of who visited it (see `visitors`). After I run it, if I inspect the turtles on screen they all contain lists that I would expect. For example each buyer has a list of 5 houses visited and each house has approximately 5 buyers. A typical buyer looks like this: [attributes of a buyer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5FmT.png).
Note the list of 5 houses visited.

However if I run BehaviorSpace and ask for the reporters

```
[visited] of buyers
[visitors] of houses
```

then I get lists running to several thousand long - this is currently with just 1 repetition and a time limit of 1000.

The output looks as follows:

[spreadsheet output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvlFi.png)

[table output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fW9o2.png)

I have reported agent attributes before with no problem - I cannot see what is different here.

Comment: Hi Kevin, it would be very useful if you provided a [mre] of the unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify any stop condition, either in-code or in your BehaviorSpace setup.

I saw from the image you originally posted about the BhaviorSpace setup, that you included a `Time limit` of 1000. I imagine you got there because, with the default value of 0, BehaviorSpace experiments were running forever. With experiments stopping only once they hit the specified time limit, your `buyers` are continuing to do what they're told for much longer than just 5 repetitions - hence the very long lists.

In your case, since you are already telling NetLogo how many times you want your `go` to execute (by using `repeat`), and based on the arrangement of your code (i.e. `tick` happening only after all your desired repetitions took place), either of the following stop conditions will achieve what you want:

- In BehaviorSpace: `ticks = 1`;
- In code:

```
to go
  repeat 5 [
    ...
  ]

  tick
  stop
end
```

In both cases, you can just go back to having a `Time limit` of 0 (i.e. no time limit).

Comment: Thank you  - perfect. May I ask a  follow-up related question?  Why are the buyers continuing to act if they are in  a  repeat 5 [  ] ? I think my confusion here is that tick does not play a part - there is no flow of time, each buyer matches to a house and then should stop, and yet we have the stop after the tick.   -IGNORE - it ticks once and then stops !

Comment: @KevinA Every time you execute `go`, each `buyer` will do their stuff 5 times and then stop, yes (to be precise, you will ask 5 times all `buyers` to do their stuff, and then they stop because they have nothing left to do). However what BehaviorSpace does is that it continues to hit the 'Go command' (in your case `go`) until a specified stop condition happens. This is how BehaviorSpace works and it is desirable, because it is the equivalent of a human activating a forever-button. So, if you don't specify that stop condition, what BehaviorSpace does is equal to you hitting on `go` forever.